# How to determine if provider is for SQL Server or SQLite?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I am configuring my entities by having an `EntityConfiguration` class that implements `IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>`.

For normal application execution I am using SQL Server and for unit testing I am using SQLite.

The issue is that the SQLite provider has limited features, so I would like to conditionally configure my entities so that if it is using SQL Server, it has additional features, such as `RowVersion`:

```
entity.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
      .IsRequired(true)
      .IsRowVersion()
      .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

How can I tell which db provider is being used?

Comment: I would not do this because it's introducing code complexity for the sake of unit tests.  A better solution might be to create integration tests using TestContainers that can spin up a throw away instance of SQLServer.

Comment: In addition to what @Fran said, the practice of unit testing using a different DBMS than will actually be used is questionable at best.

Comment: Consider trying [postgresql](https://postgresql.org/) locally one your Linux laptop

Comment: I recently did exactly what @Fran outlines. `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` got me a schema-only copy of the DB, which I attached to my dev machine's LocalDB installation. As part of the unit tests, each test reverts to a snapshot of the test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments to the question give good reasoning why NOT to do it in the code - use the same type of the database in your tests.

But if you still want to do it - I could only think of putting this logic both in the db context and entity type configuration. Please see demo below

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer("xxx"));
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
// trigger entity configuration
dbContext.Orders.ToList();


public class Orders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class OrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Orders>
{
    private readonly string provider;

    public OrderConfiguration(string provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Orders> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        
        if (provider == "SqlServer")
        {
            builder.Property(x => x.RowVersion)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken()
                ;
        }
    }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        string provider = null;
        if (Database.IsSqlServer())
        {
            provider = "SqlServer";
        }

        // do this or load different configuration type for each provider
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new OrderConfiguration(provider)); 
        
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```